# Residue at a pole

Tags: residue-calculus

In my textbook, I have this example:

$$f(z) = \frac{9z+i}{z^3+z}.$$ Find the residue.

So the book says it has a simple pole at $i$ but doesn't it also have a simple pole at $-i$?

I can see the denominator is $z(z^2 + 1) = z(z+i)(z-i)$ so doesn't it have three simple poles: $z = 0, z = i, z = -i$?

The residue that the book gives is:

$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=i} \frac{9z+i}{z(z^2+1)} = \lim_{z \to i} (z-i) \frac{9z+i}{z(z+i)(z-i)} = \frac{9z+i}{z(z+i)}\bigg|_{z=i} = \frac{10i}{-2} = -5i$$

But aren't there other poles?

Comment: How did you set up your contour? $-i$ may not be in it

Comment: Yes, there are other poles, but we don't have to consider them in order to compute the residue at  $z=i$

Comment: If the example really asks "find the residue," then it is ambiguous; one should ask "find the residue at [singularity] $i$" or something like that.

Comment: My book does not say anything of the sort.

Comment: Is the problem $\frac{9z+1}{z^3+z}$ or $\frac{9z+i}{z^3+z}$? You have both formulae in your question.

Comment: It's an i in the numerator @MathKeepsMeBusy

Comment: thanks for fixing it.

Comment: In total agreement with @angryavian , I would remind you that any text book is not written by a divinity but by a human being. Text have plenty of mistakes, especially in the exercises and their answers.

Comment: @angryavian I think my book was a bit ambiguous but I may have misinterpreted. IT says that f(z) has a simple pole and i, but not that it was the only simple pole. I think I misinterpreted and just wanted to make sure that it clearly had other simple poles.